# Starting two different activities for two different user type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When user is Logged in with the userType "student", shows `MainActivity` and for the "teacher", shows `MainActivityTeacher`. 
I am trying to adjust the `onStart()` function in my `LoginActivity` since it has the action.MAIN.

Tried to get current user's userType and if the userType is student, `SendToMainActivity()`  and if the userType is teacher, `SendToMainActivityTeacher()` but I don't know how to get it.
Also, I tried to get parent of ex) xTfg4if4yLQ75zRq889pJkmCBsh1 user by using .`parent()` so that I can use the string students or teachers but it was getting the `string` of my project name.

Firebase Database:

```
  Students
     - 7x7novsG59UsFa1QyBp4K8bd2X82
         - userType: "student"
         - username: "student00"
  Teachers
     - xTfg4if4yLQ75zRq889pJkmCBsh1
         - userType: "teacher"
         - username: "teacher01@gmail.com"
```

Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    String currUserId = currentUser.getUid();
    DatabaseReference dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(currUserId).getParent();
    String StrDataRef = dataRef.toString();
    dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userType = dataSnapshot.getValue();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already done. Just add this line of code:

```
String userType = (String) dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue();

if(userType == "student"){
// goto student activity
}else if(userType == "teacher") {
// goto teacher activity
}
```

Or you can use **POJO Class** Like below

```
UserType userType = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserType.class); // create a class named UserType

if(userType.type == "student"){
    // goto student activity
}else if(userType.type == "teacher") {
    // goto teacher activity
}
```

Comment: I put that inside the onDataChange method and getting Null pointer error. Tried to see whats saved inside the userType String but doesn't show anything like student or teacher. Something wrong with my DatabaseReference?

Comment: Yeah there is problem in your DatabaseReference. You didn't add Students Or Teachers in your databaseReference. `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students/" + currUserId)` or `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Teachers/" + currUserId)`

Comment: If I am logged in with teacher and the DatabaseReference is setup with FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students/" + currUserId), it doesn't work because I am trying to fine teacher in Students/. Should I create two different DatabaseReference like you mentioned?

Comment: If you are logged in as Teacher then `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Teachers/" + currUserId)` is for you

Comment: so whenever I log in with different user type, I have to open the android studio and change "Teachers/" or "Students/"? I want it to automatically check if it is teacher or student by using currentUserId.

Comment: You can save to SharedPreference when a user is logged in as Students or Teachers. Assume your variable is `String type`. Then you can use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(type + currUserId)` like this

Comment: Got the idea. Thank you !!

Comment: You can accept :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your user in `onCreate()` method like

```
if(userType == "student"){
// set student layout
}else if(userType == "teacher") {
// set teacher layout
}
```

and use `setContentView()` method.
In this case you will have one activity, but you should have two different layouts for them.

**OR**

If you have login activity, you can put as launcher activity this login page and check here does this user teacher or not and redirect the user to necessary activity.

Comment: How can I get the userType from the database?